# Replace a Condition within an expression

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

I have a simple expression containing a `Condition`(s) like

```
a /; a > 1
```

I wish to separate the expression from the condition, to display like

```
| expr | cond  |
----------------
| a    | a > 1 |
```

How can I obtain the sub-expression `a` from the expression `a /; a > 1`?
Attempting to remove the `Condition`s by `Replace` doesn't seem to work, probably because the `Condition` in the pattern is being interpreted at the top-level:

```
in = a /; a > 1

in /. Condition[expr_, cond_] :> expr
in /. HoldPattern[Condition[expr_, cond_]] :> expr
in /. Unevaluated[Condition[expr_, cond_]] :> expr
in /. Verbatim[Condition[expr_, cond_]] :> expr
```

These all output the unchanged input:

```
>>> a /; a > 1
```

Here's a hacky workaround:

```
in /. Condition -> dummy /. dummy[expr_,cond_] :> expr
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: try `in /. Verbatim[Condition][expr_, cond_] :> expr`?

Comment: and `in /. HoldPattern[Condition][expr_, cond_] :> expr`

Comment: @kglr aw yep, how clumsy of me, thanks!

Comment: you can also use `in /. Condition -> (# &)` and `in /. c_Condition :> First[c]`

Comment: @kglr You could convert these comments into an answer. The only problem I have is with   the version `HoldPattern[Condition][expr_, cond_]` - I think this is a misuse of `HoldPattern`, which is used where `Verbatim` should be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
in = a /; a > 1
```

Using `Verbatim[Condition]` instead of `Condition` gives the expected result

```
in /. Verbatim[Condition][expr_, cond_] :> expr
```

> ```
> a
> ```

You can also use

```
in /. Condition -> (# &)

in /. c_Condition :> First[c]
```

The following also work

```
in /. (foo : Condition)[expr_, cond_] :> expr

in /. HoldPattern[Condition][expr_, cond_] :> expr

in /. PatternSequence[Condition][expr_, cond_] :> expr

in /. Alternatives[Condition][expr_, cond_] :> expr
```

The last three, as noted by Leonid in comments, are *misuses* of `HoldPattern`, `PatternSequence`, and `Alternatives`.